# What is an appropriate HTTP response code for a file that already exists?

Tags: http

I was wondering what is the right HTTP ERROR CODE for someone that is trying to:

```
PUT /newfile.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost
```

What's the appropriate error code if the client wants to add a file that already exists? I don't know what to use ... I have looked at the RFC but can't find a appropriate code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s a rarely used response code, but it seems to me that [`409 Conflict`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.10) might be the best fit for your needs:

> The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current
>   state of the resource. This code is only allowed in situations where
>   it is expected that the user might be able to resolve the conflict and
>   resubmit the request. The response body SHOULD include enough
>   information for the user to recognize the source of the conflict.
>   Ideally, the response entity would include enough information for the
>   user or user agent to fix the problem; however, that might not be
>   possible and is not required.
>
> Conflicts are most likely to occur in response to a PUT request. For
>   example, if versioning were being used and the entity being PUT
>   included changes to a resource which conflict with those made by an
>   earlier (third-party) request, the server might use the 409 response
>   to indicate that it can't complete the request. In this case, the
>   response entity would likely contain a list of the differences between
>   the two versions in a format defined by the response Content-Type.

Answer (score 2):

[409 Conflict](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.10) or another from the 400 range like 428 will work, but arguably, you break REST if you don't allow the client to overwrite a resource using a PUT.

PUT should be idempotent, and if you refuse to execute the command based on what's already there, idempotence is broken.